# Failed to run "npm install" in Vue3 composition api

Tags: node.js, npm, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to install dependences in Vue3 project, but I get an error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vuejs-v-3@0.1.30
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.31
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@">= 2.5 < 3" from @vue/composition-api@1.4.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm ERR!   @vue/composition-api@"^1.4.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

I try use 'npm i --force' comand, but it don´t work...

should i make a downgrade in node version, or npm, or vue?

thanks

Comment: Could you please give us more context? What is happening here? What did you typed exactly? Where are you? Anything that could be helpful. [ask]

Comment: I've just added that dependency to my project with the same version of vue, works fine. What npm version do you have?

Comment: Looks like `@vue/composition-api` requires `vue@">= 2.5 < 3"` so either you have to downgrade vue or remove/upgrade/fork `@vue/composition-api`

Comment: Sure... My node version is v16.14.2 and npm is 8.1.3. I try run "npm install". The instalation starting putting the 'node_modules' in project but broke in the middle of instalations and remove that folder. Broke saying that "node-sass" is not compatible. So I remove that from package.json. Run 'npm install' again and show me now that 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NormalModule')...

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade vue version to "vue": "^3.3.0"
It worked for me